# ActiveRecord class association

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

Let's pretend that we have two tables, Posts and Categories, that have a many to one relationship, one category to many posts. Which would be the best way to go about defining that in the class definitions?

1. Just Category { has_many Posts }
2. Just Post { belongs_to Category }
3. Both Category { has_many Posts } AND Post { belongs_to Category }

Comment: btw: are you using the phpactiverecord library? (phpactiverecord.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to be able to do something like `myCategory->Posts` if you have a category, but also `myPost->categories`, you want to define both relations.